# base64 encoded images, submit input buttons and failing title tags

Tags: css, image, forms, button, base64

I'm trying to use a base64 encoded image in a submit input button on a small form. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<input type="image" border="0" class="my-but my-but-4" title="bla bla bla" />
```

The base64 encoded image is located in an attached stylesheet and everything work perfectly in Chrome v32 and Safari v5.1.7, but the title text fails in Firefox v26 and IE v9 under Windows Vista.

In other words there is weird text or broken images appearing over the actual working image in the background.

Has anyone else tried attaching a base64 encoded image to a form button before?

Vince

Comment: Could you make up a demo of this? (CodePen or jsFiddle etc.)

Comment: @ralph.m I've never used either before and I don't know how either would work within the various browsers.

Comment: `I don't know how either would work within the various browsers.` That's the whole point, really. An online example is easy to open in a range of browsers. CodePen is my preferred, but you could also just post code for a text HTML page here instead, with CSS in the head.

Comment: @vince go to jsfiddle, paste your html and css. Or atleast enough to reproduce the problem. Then hit save, and share the jsfiddle link with us.

Comment: @ralph.m I also prefer codepen, but jsfiddle is easy to get right to the point.

Comment: @natewiley Got it, thank you nate, I never needed to use such tools before and had no idea how easy it was to use.  Here's the link, [http://jsfiddle.net/AjsVB/](http://jsfiddle.net/AjsVB/)